# limit query time in the client side of PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, limit

I'm trying to query the PostgreSQL database, but this is a public server and I really don't want to waste a lot of CPU for a long time.

So I wonder if there is some way to limit my query time for a specific duration, for example, 3/5/10 minutes.

I assume that there is syntax like `limit` but not for results amount but for query duration.

Comment: There is statement_timeout.  But you could argue that running  query for 10 minutes only to get an error and throw away whatever work was already done is even more wasteful.  Are you looking to get partial results?  Or to predict how long the query will take, and refuse to even start executing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `statement_timeout`, then your query will be terminated with an error if it exceeds that limit.

According to [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/runtime-config-client.html) documentation:

> statement_timeout (integer)
>
> Abort any statement that takes more than
> the specified number of milliseconds, starting from the time the
> command arrives at the server from the client. If
> log_min_error_statement is set to ERROR or lower, the statement that
> timed out will also be logged. A value of zero (the default) turns
> this off.
>
> Setting statement_timeout in postgresql.conf is not recommended
> because it would affect all sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential catch with using `LIMIT` to control how long a query might run.  Rightfully, you ought to also be using `ORDER BY` with your query, to tell Postgres how exactly it should limit the size of the result set.  But the caveat here is that Postgres would typically have to materialize the entire result set when using `LIMIT` with `ORDER BY`, and then also possibly sort, which might take longer than just reading in the entire result set.

One workaround to this might be to just use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.  If the execution plan does not include reading the entire table and sorting, it might be one way to do what you want.  However, keep in mind that if you go this route, Postgres would have free license to return *any* records from the table it wishes, in any order.  This is probably not what you want from a business or reporting point of view.

But, a much better approach here would be just tune your query using things like indices, and make it faster to the point where you don't need to resort to a `LIMIT` trick.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I know the caveats of  `limit`. I want a way to stop the query after some time to avoid overloading the server.

Comment: And my answer is to not even get to the point where you need to do this.  Know your data, know your queries, and don't let this happen.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your attitude.